# How do you transfer a inputstream from a ftp server directly to S3 multipart Upload?

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, sftp, jsch

I am trying to upload a large file (aprrox 2gb to 3gb) from a client's FTP server to my Amazon S3 bucket location.
 Now I am not allowed to store the whole of the file in my remote application server, so no intermediate stop is allowed. Also I have no other access right to the client ftp server other than to SFTP.
Is there any particular way you may suggest ??

Also right now I am using JSCH library to read the file in Ftp server as a Inputstream and then pass the same Inputstream to the UploadPartRequest. Also please note that I am able to recieve the file size from the client using the JSCH library so as to make multipart file.
Here's the sample code I've been trying out.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
    try {
        long partSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
        jsch= new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpLocation, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setTimeout(0);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("session connected ......" + session.isConnected());
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("channel connected...." + channel.isConnected());
        c = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        SftpATTRS attrs = c.lstat(filePath);
        long contentLength = attrs.getSize();
        InputStream is = c.get(filePath);
        System.out.println("size of the file in remote location is : " + contentLength/(1024*1024) +" MB" );
        long filePosition = 0;
        for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
            partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest().withBucketName(existingBucketName)
                    .withKey(keyName).withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                    .withPartNumber(i).withFileOffset(filePosition).withInputStream(is).withPartSize(partSize);
            boolean anotherPass;
            do {
                anotherPass = false;
                try {
                    partETags.add(s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    anotherPass = true;
                }
            } while (anotherPass);

        filePosition += partSize;
            System.out.println("new file pos is : " + filePosition/(1024*1024) +" MB");
        }
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(existingBucketName, keyName, initResponse.getUploadId(), partETags);
        s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception occurred : " + ex.getMessage());
        s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(
                existingBucketName, keyName, initResponse.getUploadId()));
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        System.out.println("closing all connections !!!!");
        if(session != null){
            session.disconnect();
        }if(channel != null){
            channel.disconnect();
        }if(c != null){
            c.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Now with this approach when the upload reaches somewhere in the middle, then the whole upload process just stops. The application is running but there's no upload or download network to and upload stops at around 50%. 
Any suggestion guys ???

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I'd try to see where the problem is.

Firstly you could decouple this code to get a byte array buffer of a small size, like 10k, out of the FTP connection, and throw the buffer away at each iteration (don't send it to S3), to see if still hangs or not.

After if this works, you can send this byte chunks to S3 one at a time and see what happens.

Comment: Well the problem arises on size greater than 700Mb. Small files are uploaded to the s3 easily enough. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: 10k at a time for the whole 2Gb or 3Gb